# Convert type T to type U in an identity function

Tags: go, generics

With the given type signature below, is there a way to do something similar to below?

```
func Transform[T, U any](item T) U {
    return item
}
```

The code above gives the following error:

```
cannot use item (variable of type T constrained by any) as U value in return 
statement
```

I am unable to use the type signature above, as I am essentially trying to make an optional transform method that sometimes will need to convert from T to U, but sometimes just return itself. A more detailed example of the use case is shown below.

```
type SomeStruct[T, U any] struct {
    Transform func(T) U
}

func (s SomeStruct[T, U]) Transform(elem T) (U) {
    if s.Transform != nil {
        return s.Transform(elem)
    }
    return elem
}
```

Is there a way to create a Transform function that sometimes conditionally just returns itself?

Comment: No, you cannot create a function that has varying return types (or argument types, for that matter). You can have it return an interface type, but that's about it.

Comment: I'm trying to write code that accepts a transform function, but the transform function is optional. In the case that it's not provided, I want to be able to use the original value T, but was running into issues where the compiler requires me to convert it into a U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your code snippet work:

```
func Transform[T, U any](item T) U {
    return any(item).(U)
}
```

But the code **will fail with a panic** if `U` is not [assertion-compatible](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) with the actual type of `item`:

This will panic:

```
fmt.Println(Transform[string, int]("foo"))

// Output: panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not int
```

This succeeds without panic, because `bytes.Buffer` is implements both the `io.Reader` and `io.Writer` interface:

```
b := &bytes.Buffer{}
_ = Transform[io.Writer, io.Reader](b)
```

So, it's possible to do what you want. But I'm not sure how useful it is, as fails at runtime of the actual argument isn't compatible with `U`.

Comment: This combined with some [reflection](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50741#issuecomment-1037320881) solved my use case. The reflection is used to catch the panic case and return an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return `T` if your function is defined to return `U`. Even if you assert `T` to `U`, the function is still returning `U`.

If you really want to return exactly **either `T` or `U`**, you need to declare the return type as `any`:

```
func (s SomeStruct[T, U]) Transform(elem T) any { /* ... */ }
```

...which gives up static typing; or you could use a helper "either" type:

```
type Either[T, U any] struct {
    value any
}

// Either methods

func (s SomeStruct[T, U]) Transform(elem T) Either[T, U] {
    if s.transform == nil {
        return Either[T, U]{elem}
    }
    return Either[T, U]{s.transform(elem)}
}
```

See how to use it in [this playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ujb1Pdb_Ojc).

---

Alternatives will deviate from your stated goal. One is to actually assert `T` to `U`, though you must be aware that this returns `U`, not `T`, even if `T`'s value is assignable to `U`:

```
func (s SomeStruct[T, U]) Transform(elem T) U {
    if s.transform == nil {
        if u, ok := any(elem).(U); ok {
            return u
        }
        return *new(U) // U's zero value if elem assertion fails
    }
    return s.transform(elem)
}
```

You must use an assertion because both type parameters `T` and `U` are constrained by `any`, so there's (rightfully) no other way to express [convertibility](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) between the two. The comma-ok idiom helps avoid run-time panics.

Or you can return `(U, error)` instead, *which is, generally, the reasonable thing to do*:

```
func (s SomeStruct[T, U]) Transform(elem T) (u U, err error) {
    if s.transform == nil {
        err = errors.New("transform function not set")
        return 
    }
    u = s.transform(elem)
    return
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/GKLRmKKWxlP